# Homomorphism between $Q_8$ and $S_4$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Prove that there does not exist a homomorphism $\phi :Q_8 \rightarrow S_4$ such that $\phi (i) = (1 2 3 4), \phi (j) = (1 2 4 3) $.

Using homomorphism properties, we obtain $\phi(i) \phi(j) = \phi(ij) = \phi(k) = (1 2 3 4)(1 2 4 3) = (1 3 2)$, then $\phi(j) \phi(k) = \phi(jk) = \phi(i) = (1 2 4 3)(1 3 2) = (3 4)\neq (1 3 2)$, hence $\phi$ is not even a well-defined function. Is what I did right? I am not completely convinced. Thanks!

Comment: Right idea, but I'd check the details. Don't you want to obtain a value of $\phi(i) \neq (1234)$ for a contradiction?

Comment: @bounceback yes this is exactly what I did: the second calculation maps $i$ to $(3 4)$ instead of $(1 2 3 4)$, which is the contradiction.

Comment: Wouldn't another contradiction from $\phi(k)=(132)$ be that we need $k^4=1$?  (That would involve less computation.)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yeah I found a couple other ways too, but this particular one seemed a bit iffy, so I wanted to be completely sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculations are good and your proof is right, you could perhaps word it the following way to make the logic crystal clear:

- Let $\phi$ be some arbitrary function from $Q_8$ to $S_4$ that happens to take $i$ to $(1234)$ and $j$ to $(1243)$.
- Let's show that $\phi$ is not a homomorphism.
- If $\phi$ were a homomorphism, then $\phi(i) = \phi(jij) = \phi(j)\phi(i)\phi(j)$. But this implies
  $$
  (1234) = (1243)(1234)(1243)
  $$
  which is false: the right hand side fixes $1$ and the left hand side doesn't.

Comment: (Put another way, there's plenty of honest-to-goodness functions from $Q_8$ to $S_4$ and you are showing that they can't satisfy three things at once: (taking $i$ to $(1234)$, taking $j$ to $(1243)$, and being a homomorphism).

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is correct. There is another, perhaps simpler argument:
$$
(1234)^2=(13)(24),\qquad (1243)^2=(14)(23)
$$
so $\phi(i^2)=(\phi(i))^2=(13)(24)$. On the other hand $\phi(j^2)=(14)(23)$. A contradiction, because $i^2=j^2=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it is not much harder to show that there is no homomorphism $\varphi:Q_8\to S_4$ such that $\varphi(i)=(1234)$.
(In other words, we don't even need the hypothesis on $\varphi(j)$.)

Here is a sketch of the proof. Since $S_4$ does not contain a subgroup isomorphic to $Q_8$ (such a subgroup would be a Sylow $2$-subgroup, but those are dihedral), it follows that $\varphi$ cannot be injective. So the kernel of $\varphi$ is non-trivial. Now, $Q_8$ has a unique minimal normal subgroup, namely $\langle -1\rangle$, so this must be contained in the kernel. So  $\varphi(i)^2=\varphi(i^2)=\varphi(-1)$ is the identity.